# Flow of program not what was expected

Tags: c#

Building a simple app here; the methods in question:

static coin class

```
public static void SetUpCoins() {
        coin1 = new Coin(); 
        coin2 = new Coin();
    }

 public static void PlayConsole() {
        SetUpCoins();
        OutputWinner();            
    }


      public static void OutputWinner() {

        if (coin1.ToString() == "Heads" && coin2.ToString() == "Heads") {
            Console.WriteLine("You threw Heads - you win");
            ++point_player;
        } else if (coin1.ToString() == "Tails" && coin2.ToString() == "Tails") {
            Console.WriteLine("You threw Tails - I win");
            ++point_comp;
        } else {
           Console.WriteLine("You threw Odds");
           WaitForKey_ConsoleOnly("Press any key to throw again");
           PlayConsole();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} points and the computer has {1} points", point_player, point_comp);

        if (WantToPlayAgain_ConsoleOnly()) { // ask user if they want to play again; return bool
            PlayConsole();
        }
      }

 private static bool WantToPlayAgain_ConsoleOnly() {
            string input;
            bool validInput = false;
            do {
                Console.Write("Play Again? (Y or N): ");
                input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                validInput = input == "Y" || input == "N";
            } while (!validInput);

            return input == ("Y"); 
        }
```

If `false` was to return from `WantToPlayAgain_ConsoleOnly()` the program does not exit. Here is an example of the output, which explains my problem:

[image]

Why, when `WantToPlayAgain_ConsoleOnly` is false, does the program not pass control the `playConsole` method then exit. instead of this repetition.

After `OutputWinner` is finished running, it then jumps into `PlayConsole`, and then  back into the else statement of the `OutputWinner` - not sure why.

Comment: Please put code of WantToPlayAgain_ConsoleOnly()

Comment: How come you can do `new Coin()` when `Coin` is static ?

Comment: Your issue is fundamental code structure. Specifically, the problem is the recursion caused in the "Odds" case - breakpoint, step through and you'll see exactly what's happening there.

Comment: @JohnArlen I think your right. and thats what I'm not sure of, why does it go back into that else? and how do I fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the previous answers said, you have a problem when you throw odds. 
Because at that point you call the exact same method again and when that call returns, you resume right at the score display and the player is asked again to play.
Because you are calling `PlayConsole` recursively, that means for every time you throw "Odd", you will get one more prompt that you didn't ask for.

You could restructure the method like this:

```
  public static void OutputWinner() {
    do {
        // Game code
    }
    while (WantToPlayAgain_ConsoleOnly());
  }
```

That also gets rid of the recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are calling PlayConsole() after "Press any key to throw again". Once that call returns the program will unconditionally continue with "You have {0} points and the computer has {1} points", regardless of what happened during the call.

Try rewriting the logic to be iterative rather than recursive?

Comment: Yes, I could :-) But this is something you should be able to figure out on your own.